# Is it possible to create table/views under a package in the schema?

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, sql-server-2012, database-schema

> In MS SQL Server 2012/oracle, I need to create something like a.b.c
>   where c is the table/view name, b is the package name and a is the
>   schema name.
>
> I wanted to create a table/view in two levels. I couldn't find any
>   proper document regarding this. Any suggestion to find the good document 
>   will be helpful.

Comment: No idea what you're trying to ask, but this might be relevant:    Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS SQL Server and Oracle are very different.  They're both relational DBs, but different vendors and don't function quite the same.  There are similarities though.
At any rate, you don't create tables under a package.  A table is an object much like a package is an object.  A package is designed to hold a collection of procedures/functions within Oracle.  SQL Server doesn't even implement packages.

So, as an Oracle example, the best you're going to get is Database > account (or schema..) > table.